# skip 2 lines after a match while reading from a file

Tags: python, match, lines

I am trying to code something where I first look for some string in a line in a txt file and when it is found I want to skip that row and the row below to get a new txt file without those rows. I really didn't get any solution from other questions here so maybe this will work

My code looks like this now:

```
with open("bla.txt", "r+") as f
    new_f = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in new_f:
        if "abc" not in line:
            f.write(line)
        else:
            pass
            pass
    f.truncate()
```

I tried it with `next(f)` aswell but it didn't work for me. thanks in advance

Comment: what is your sample input and expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a new file that skip the current and next row if the current row has the string ABC:

```
with open('bla.txt','r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    lines = text.split('\n')
with open('new_file.txt','w') as nf:
    l = 0
    while l<(len(lines)):
        if 'ABC' in lines[l]:
            l = l+2
        else:
            nf.write(lines[l]+'\n')
            l = l+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple like this:

```
import os

search_for = 'abc'

with open('input.txt') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as o:
  for line in f:
    if search_for in line:
       next(f) # we need to skip the next line
               # since we are already processing
               # the line with the string
               # in effect, it skips two lines
    else:
       o.write(line)

os.rename('output.txt', 'input.txt')
```

Here is a [repl with sample code](https://repl.it/repls/EllipticalSlategreyCompilers).